# Enceladus plumes particle fx

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am asking for help because I am not that experienced with the particle generator, and I want to create the Enceladus plumes effect. I currently have the scene with the whole Saturn system,  using Cycles, and I have the probe near Enceladus, in the region of plumes. And I want to make the plumes touch the probe. And I don't have an idea how to do the plumes. 
I want to recreate this:

[image: large backlit geysers rising from enceladus]

Comment: I suggest using a volumetric texture for distant shots, and particles for the closeups against the probe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can use a lot of translucent particles

(But you may prefer a more fuzzy (i.e. volumetric) solution)

**The result:**

[image]

This is my setup:

1. a planet (diffuse white sphere),
2. an atmosphere (bigger sphere with a "*Volume Scatter*" material),
3. a distant area lamp representing the Sun,
4. a monkey shaped probe
5. a randomly subdivided plane with a white "*Translucent Shader*" as material

[image]

The planet has a **Particle System** emitting 1000 particles, with a "Child" duplication set to 200 (but higher numbers will give you fuzzier plumes, and longer renders).

The particles are emitted slowly along the Normal (0.100) and have a fair amount of Brownian force (0.360). They are not affected by the scene gravity  (Gravity Field weight = 0). They are rendered as "Object" using the subdivided plane as the Duplication object.

You can play a lot with the settings to make it look right. These are my settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]

This can also be used in animation: the plumes are dynamic -- even if maybe too fast with my settings.

[image]

I attach my blend file if you want to have a look at how it works.

[image]